# Using .not, :not, and .toggle to show a <div> and remove others

Tags: jquery, html

I have three different div's that I'd like to alternate between.  If another div is showing, I'd like it to go away before the other appears.  The code I have works for two div's but when I add the third, it doesn't work.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here.  I searched through other threads, but haven't had any luck with a solution.  Any help or redirection to an appropriate thread would be greatly appreciated. (I apoologize if this is a repeat question)

http://codepen.io/DogburnDesign/pen/izdwl

HTML:

```
<button><h1 data-target="#one">One is Green</h1></button>
<button><h1 data-target="#two">Two is Red</h1></button>
<!--<button><h1 data-target="#three">Three is Blue</button>-->
<div class="blocks" id="one"></div>
<div class="blocks" id="two"></div>
<!--<div class="blocks" id="three"></div>-->
```

jQuery:

```
$("h1").click(function(){
var buttonclicked = $(this).data("target");

  if($(".blocks:not(buttonclicked)").is(":visible")){
    $(".blocks").not(buttonclicked).fadeOut(function(){
    $(buttonclicked).toggle();
    });
  } else{
    $(buttonclicked).toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: ".blocks:not(buttonclicked)" it's not ok, unless buttonclicked is a tag name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that makes it work, because the error was in calling you toogle function in executing methods of a collection, on the first pass because he was visible and in the second he did disappear (because you had two elements running the function)

```
$("h1").click(function(){
   var buttonclicked = $(this).data("target");
   var blocks = $(".blocks").not(buttonclicked);
   if(blocks.is(":visible")){
      blocks.fadeOut(1);
   }  
  $(buttonclicked).fadeIn(2);
});
```

Comment: THAT DID IT!!  Thanks so much.  I thought it might be a problem with the variable and sequencing.

Where can I send flowers... or beer?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have used your variable in quotes. You should separate it like:

```
$('.blocks:not(' + buttonclicked + ').is('visible')
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for toggling each one individually, but the functionality of clicking one while another is visible, still isn't working.  Works with two still, but the addition of the third div messes with something.  Is where I'm declaring the variable messing it up maybe?